# Conditional Recoding - Using a Vector of Columns within Mutate_at Together with If_else and Dplyr::Recode

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Using the sample code below, I want to create a new variable "Filter", that recodes the variables ending is "s" (q25s,q26s,etc...), based on the value of the corresponding non "s" variable. So for example, if q25 = 1, then q25s will be recoded so that 1 = 0, 2=0, 3=0, 4=1, 5=1, and 88=Missing. If q25 doesn't equal 1, then Filter should be 0. This pattern will be repeated for all the other sets of variables.

However, in order to achieve this I'm attempting to use tidyverse to create a named vector of column names called "cols", and then use this within a "mutate_at" function together with "if_else" and dplyr::recode.

Below is an attempt but it doesn't seem to work. How should I correct the code? I'm open to other suggestions as well as long as tidyverse is used and the code is compact and no more than two lines if possible...

```
cols<-c(q25:q29)

Df<-Df%>%mutate_at(vars(q25s:q29s),funs(Filter=if_else(!!cols=1,recode  (.,`1`="a",`2`="b",`3`="c",`4`="d",`5`="e"),"Missing")))
```

How can I achieve this using tidyverse?

Here is the sample code:

```
q25<-c(2,1,88,2,1)
q26<-c(2,88,88,88,2)
q27<-c(2,2,1,1,1)
q28<-c(88,1,1,2,2)
q29<-c(1,1,1,2,2)
q25s<-c(3,5,88,4,1)
q26s<-c(4,4,5,5,1)
q27s<-c(3,3,4,1,4)
q28s<-c(4,5,88,1,3)
q29s<-c(88,88,3,4,4)
Df<-data.frame(q25,q26,q27,q28,q29,q25s,q26s,q27s,q28s,q29s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to subset the dataset by including columns that start with 'q' followed by numbers ('q\d+') and  'q' followed by numbers followed by 's' ('q\d+s'), then with `map2`, use the `ifelse` to change the corresponding columns to `letters` based on value 1 in 'q\d+' columns

```
library(tidyverse)
cols<-paste0("q", 25:29)
cols1 <- paste0(cols, "s")
Df[cols1] <- map2(Df[cols], Df[cols1], ~ifelse(.x == 1, letters[.y], .y) %>%
                             replace(., is.na(.), "Missing") )

Df
#  q25 q26 q27 q28 q29 q25s q26s q27s    q28s    q29s
#1   2   2   2  88   1    3    4    3       4 Missing
#2   1  88   2   1   1    e    4    3       e Missing
#3  88  88   1   1   1   88    5    d Missing       c
#4   2  88   1   2   2    4    5    a       1       4
#5   1   2   1   2   2    a    1    d       3       4
```

---

Or using only `base R`

```
Df[cols1] <- Map(function(x,y) {
                 x1 <- ifelse(x == 1, letters[y], y)
                 replace(x1, is.na(x1), "Missing")
                 },
                      Df[cols], Df[cols1])
```

Comment: I forgot an important aspect of the question...if it's too much to change the code I can accept this answer and ask another modified one. I forgot to add that I would like to create new variables based on the recoding...for example q25_new, q26_new, etc.

Comment: Hi again, I created a new question to further expand the answer to this one. It would be great if you could take a look at it too! It's titled - "Using Purrr::map2 to Loop Over Two Vectors of Column Names in Order to Conditionally Recode Multiple Columns into New Variables",.